# Need to insert the data to the running kafka stream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

Kafka stream is running continuously and storing the events in some location, and now i need to insert some records to that location.
i tried using the below Merge command

```
MERGE INTO new_table
USING old_table
on new_table.id=old_table.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
```

I have stopped the kafka stream and ran the above query, after running that the data were added to that location and then when i start the stream again i am loosing all those data and the stream consuming new records.

can anyone help me to know how to insert records to running stream.

Comment: Kafka Streams doesn't have "merge into" commands. Please clarify what you're using